# Set Cache Control for Rails Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got the following code in my application_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_cache_headers

def set_cache_headers
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

This causes my assets to reload at each request too. In Rails, how do I make the HTML reload on each request but not the assets?

I want something like this (except within Rails):

```
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|JPG|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to action_controller caching ON by default in Rails for Prod env, the Control-Cache is also set. But your filter in ApplicationController is overwriting that, thereby disabling cache as a whole. 
Try sticking this line in your config/initializers/assets.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{some_number}"
}
```

For `some_number` you need a value in seconds, e.g. `30.days.to_i` .